# difference in using と and で to specify context

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference in using a と and で　in the sentence:

そう、女の子に取って貰い たて、口の横にわざ**と**ソースを 付けている ツン ツン 頭のメガネも

Comment: What do you imagine わざで would mean here? わざと is a set expression.

Comment: @Leebo I'd thought わざ means purposely/intentionally and hence わざで is specifying it's on purpose. For example: わざで飲む. Drank it on purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

わざと is a fixed adverb listed on any dictionary. It does not inflect, and you should treat it as one word that means "intentionally" or "purposely".

わざ (業) on its own is an old word meaning "action", "act" or "behavior". Etymologically, わざと is indeed わざ followed by と, but that does not mean わざで means something in modern Japanese. Basically you need to memorize わざと without worrying about its etymology too much. Imagine English words like "meanwhile" or "nevertheless", which were fossilized long ago and have unique menings.